# Bruteforcing PCP's in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, number-systems

I am trying to Bruteforce a PCP that is supposed to be up to the length 300.

I wrote a little Python program that is doing just that but it could take forever until my program finds the right PCP.

```
import sys

x1 = "aba"
x2 = "a"
x3 = "bab"
y1 = "a"
y2 = "ab"
y3 = "abaa"

def ternary(n):
    if n == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        e = n//3
        q = n%3
        return ternary(e) + str(q)

x = 1; 

while True:
    ter = ternary(x)
    ter = ("%01d" % (float(ter),))
    #print("ter = " + str(ter))
    wordx = ""
    wordy = ""
    for i in range(0, len(str(ter))):
        if(str(ter)[i] == '0'):
            wordx = wordx + x1
        if(str(ter)[i] == '1'):
            wordx = wordx + x2
        if(str(ter)[i] == '2'):
            wordx = wordx + x3
    for j in range(0, len(str(ter))):
        if(str(ter)[j] == '0'):
            wordy = wordy + y1
        if(str(ter)[j] == '1'):
            wordy = wordy + y2
        if(str(ter)[j] == '2'):
            wordy = wordy + y3

    print(ter)


    if wordx == wordy:
        print("Wordx = " + wordx + " and wordy = " + wordy + " and the decimal number is = " + str(x) + " and the ternary number is = " + str(ter))
        sys.exit("Yes!")
    x+=1
```

Useful Information about PCP's: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem

Comment: Could you explain what a PCP is?

Comment: Sure! See I have these variables at the top (x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3). So the Turing Machine that is running a PCP like that only accepts inputs, that generate the same input with my x and my y variables.

So for example I type 112 into my Turing Machine the word produced by my x's would be: abaabaa

And my word produced by the y's would be: aaab

Which are not the same. So my task is it to find a PCP (number of inputs for that Turing Machine) that is accpetable (in this case the PCP is somewhere below 300)

Hope u dont mind the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem

Comment: You should edit the question to include that information. Comments are not supposed to be permanent.

Comment: So does your program actually work ?

Comment: Yes it does i just had to make some little changes regarding the leading zeroes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thing can be improved to make your code faster and clearer:

**Multiple useless calls to `str`**

You keep calling `str` on `ter` which is a string already. You can replace every occurence of "str(ter)" by "ter".

**The 2 loops with (apparently) different loop indices can be written in a single loop**

Unless I am missing something, the 2 loops could be written with a single loop.

**Loop like a native**

I highly recommend watching [Ned Batchelder's excellent talk "Loop like a native"](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html). In a nutshell, any time you use `range` and `len` together, there is a better way to do it.

In your case, after taking the comment above, the code becomes :

```
for c in ter:
    if c == '0':
        wordx = wordx + x1
    if c == '1':
        wordx = wordx + x2
    if c == '2':
        wordx = wordx + x3
    if c == '0':
        wordy = wordy + y1
    if c == '1':
        wordy = wordy + y2
    if c == '2':
        wordy = wordy + y3
```

**Similar conditions**

You have the same conditions evaluated twice. You could group them together.

**`elif`**

You could use `elif` between your mutually exclusive cases.

**`+=`**

You could use `a += b` instead of `a = a+b`.

Then your code becomes:

```
for c in ter:
    if c == '0':
        wordx += x1
        wordy += y1
    elif c == '1':
        wordx += x2
        wordy += y2
    elif c == '2':
        wordx += x3
        wordy += y3
```

**Single value provided to `%`**

Instead of builting a tuple with a single value via `"%01d" % (float(ter),)`, you could directly write `"%01d" % float(ter)`.

**Loop like a native again**

Instead of writing a `while True` to loop over integers, you could use `itertools.count`.

```
import itertools
for x in itertools.count(1):
    ter = "%01d" % float(ternary(x))
```

**`divmod`**

A builtin called `divmod` does exactly what your are doing in your `ternary` function.

**Final code**

Many things can still be improved but here is my current version of the code:

```
import sys
import itertools

x1 = "aba"
x2 = "a"
x3 = "bab"
y1 = "a"
y2 = "ab"
y3 = "abaa"

def ternary(n):
    if n == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        e, q = divmod(n, 3)
        return ternary(e) + str(q)

for x in itertools.count(1):
    ter = "%01d" % float(ternary(x))
    #print("ter = " + ter)
    wordx = ""
    wordy = ""
    for c in ter:
        if c == '0':
            wordx += x1
            wordy += y1
        elif c == '1':
            wordx += x2
            wordy += y2
        elif c == '2':
            wordx += x3
            wordy += y3

    if wordx == wordy:
        print("Wordx = " + wordx + " and wordy = " + wordy + " and the decimal number is = " + str(x) + " and the ternary number is = " + ter)
        sys.exit("Yes!")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The code works really well but I still have one question :P Is there a way to add exactly 1 leading zero to the number ter ? Because as soon as the number gets bigger the "%01d" wont add a leading zero anymore (I tested)

Comment: I would definitely  use either `str.format` or the fact that `print` can take multiple arguments for that final `print`...